# Vue - Vee Validate 4, validate the length of an array @submit

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I have some fields where the validation works fine and functionality where items get moved from an unselected array to a selected array. Im trying to validate the length of the selected array before submitting the form. It is required to select at least 1 item.

I'm trying to achieve the onSubmit() method is not fired when the "selected" array is empty. At the moment I'm trying to achieve this with vue's "watch()" method and vee-validates "validate()" method, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

**I am using:**

- vue 3
- vee-validate 4

**Code**

```
<template>
  <Form @submit="onSubmit">

    //some other fields where the validation works

    //functionality that puts an array item from the unselected to the selected array
    <Button>Submit</Button>
  </Form>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref, watch} from "vue/dist/vue";
import {validate, Form} from "vee-validate";

const onSubmit = () => {
  //submit form if all fields are valid
}

const selected = ref([])
const unselected = ref([
  {title: 'Bram janssen', id: 1, value: 1},
  {title: 'Bert Bertsma', id: 2, value: 2},
  {title: 'Kees Keesma', id: 3, value: 3},
  {title: 'Jan Janssen', id: 4, value: 4},
  {title: 'Pieter Pietersma', id: 5, value: 5},
  {title: 'Lars Klaver', id: 6, value: 6},
])


watch(selected.value, () => {
  validate(selected.value, {arrayLength: true})
});
</script>


//this rule lives in another file, confirmed to work
 defineRule('arrayLength', (array: any) => {
    if (array.length < 1) {
        return 'Array is empty, add at lest 1 item';
    }

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess just not with a watch. You can use the validate method directly in your "add to selected".  Working example: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vee-validate-v4-starter-composition-example-wyvxmf?file=src/App.vue)

Code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <form @submit="onSubmit">
    <p>
      <button
        @click.prevent.stop="addToArray"
      >
        Add to Array
      </button>
    </p>
    <p>Array Length: {{ myArray.length }} - array error: {{ arrayError }}</p>
    <p>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useField, useForm } from 'vee-validate';

const { handleSubmit } = useForm();
const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
});

var {
  value: myArray,
  errorMessage: arrayError,
  validate,
} = useField('myArray', (value) => 
   value.length > 0 ? true : 'Please add to the array'
);

myArray.value = [];

function addToArray(){
  myArray.value.push('abc');
  validate();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thnx alot! this was exactly what I was looking for! Cheers!